# Missing execSync in nodejs v0.10.25

Tags: javascript, node.js, synchronous

So i saw the execSync function in the nodejs api documentation.

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options

I tried to run something like this.

```
var executeSync = function(command){
  var child = require('child_process')
  code = child.execSync(command);
  return code;
}
```

But i get an error:

```
    code = child.execSync(command);
                 ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'execSync'
```

So do i get something wrong with the versions ?

```
nvm ls
    iojs-v3.3.1
         v5.0.0
->       v5.4.0
         system
default -> node (-> v5.4.0)
node -> stable (-> v5.4.0) (default)
stable -> 5.4 (-> v5.4.0) (default)
iojs -> iojs-v3.3 (-> iojs-v3.3.1) (default)
```

So why can't i use the execSync function ?

Comment: Why is the subject stating "0.10.25" but the output of `nvm` is showing that you're using 5.4.0? Which one are you using for the code?

Comment: thats a good question i also don't really get it but as it seems 5.4.0 is the npm version and 0.10.25 is the nodejs version (nodejs -v).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you installed `nodejs`, perhaps on Debian or Ubuntu, which provides an outdated Node (0.10.25).

You then installed `nvm` to allow you to run more recent versions of Node, but kept on using the `nodejs` executable instead of the `node` executable (which is the commonly used name for the Node interpreter; `nodejs` only exists on some Linux distro's because there's an unrelated `node` package that had already taken the `node` name).

In other words: run your code using `node`, not `nodejs`.

Comment: yeah that seems to be the problem. but now there is the error `(node) sys is deprecated. Use util instead.` . may you have an idea for that one too ?

Comment: @BitKoch what's the exact code that's causing that warning?

Comment: `sys = require('sys')` seems to be the problem. I guess it never said something cause i used the old version 0.10.25. node now just reminds me that i should use `util` and then everything works like a charm. Thank you for helping me figuring out this clash of versions =)